# Как привязать closest() по нажатию на button?

Tags: jquery

На странице имеется порядка 10 блоков такого типа:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src=".jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <h2></h2>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4></h4>
            <button class="button" type="button" data-uk-modal="{target:'#checkout', center:true}"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

И есть не большой jQuery скрипт, который очищает form'y по закрытию modal окна:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#checkout').on({
        'show.uk.modal': function(){
            console.log("Modal is visible.");
        },
        'hide.uk.modal': function(){
            $('#checkout-form')[0].reset();
        }
    });
});
```

Сама форма:

```
<div id="checkout">
    <form id="checkout-form" action="/wp-content/themes/wp-shop/checkout.php" method="post">
        <div>
            <h2></h2>
            <a href=""></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <i></i>
                <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Имя">
            </div>
            <div>
                <i></i>
                <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Телефон">
            </div>
            <div>
                <textarea name="message" cols="1" rows="10" id="message" placeholder="Введите сюда текст сообщения"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="error"></div>
            <button type="submit" id="checkout-button"></button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что я вторые сутки не могу разобраться с тем, как привязать `closest()` таким образом, чтобы по нажатию на `button` именно с этого блока (в котором была нажата кнопка) брался заголовок `h2` и подставлялся в `textarea` в момент открытия modal окна.

То есть, нужно чтобы относительно нажатой кнопки с верху по иерархии брался первый `h2` и передавался в форму.

Может кто то помочь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да очень просто, правда модалки в вашем коде работающей не вижу, но суть не меняется. `Closest()` применима тогда, когда можно хоть за что-то зацепиться, класс или идентификатор, у вас этого нет, проще пэрэнтами().

```js
  $(function() {
   $('button.button').on('click', function() {
    var text = $(this).parent().parent().find('h2').text();
    $('textarea[name=message]').val(text);
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <img src=".jpg"/>
   </div>
   <div class="text-center">
    <h2>h2-1</h2>
    <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h4></h4>
    <button class="button" type="button" data-uk-modal="{target:'#checkout', center:true}">0</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <img src=".jpg"/>
   </div>
   <div class="text-center">
    <h2>h2-2</h2>
    <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h4></h4>
    <button class="button" type="button" data-uk-modal="{target:'#checkout', center:true}">1</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <img src=".jpg"/>
   </div>
   <div class="text-center">
    <h2>h2-3</h2>
    <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h4></h4>
    <button class="button" type="button" data-uk-modal="{target:'#checkout', center:true}">2</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>


 <div id="checkout">
  <form id="checkout-form" action="/wp-content/themes/wp-shop/checkout.php" method="post">
   <div>
    <h2></h2>
    <a href=""></a>
   </div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <i></i>
     <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Имя">
    </div>
    <div>
     <i></i>
     <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Телефон">
    </div>
    <div>
     <textarea name="message" cols="25" rows="5" id="message" placeholder="Введите сюда текст сообщения"></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div>
    <div id="error"></div>
    <button type="submit" id="checkout-button">checkout</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень выручил